# Why does Sticky Footer break when I wrap it in 2 divs?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I was trying to implement sticky footer with zurb foundation 5.5.3 off-canvas menu for hours and I can't figure out what's causing the error.

Sticky footer works: https://codepen.io/marko_avlijas/pen/dWBJVM
When I wrap it in off canvas menu, it doesn't: https://codepen.io/marko_avlijas/pen/vmqpey

This is minimal html and css, so this question doesn't depend on codepen.
HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Sticky Footer of Unknown Height (no javascript)</h2>
    <button id="button-show">Toggle Content</button>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
    <p>Footer of variable height</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  /* ...as content is added (won't scroll) */
}
.footer {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Broken HTML

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
  <div class="inner-wrap">

    <!-- This part is same like before -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Sticky Footer Broken!!!</h2>
        <button id="button-show">Toggle Content</button>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <h3>Sticky footer</h3>
        <p>Footer of variable height</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add:

```
.off-canvas-wrap, .inner-wrap {height:100%;}
```

When you are using 100% height, the parent needs to have a fixed height... or if still want it 100%, all parents till `html`needs 100% to make it work.

Comment: This effectively cuts off every page, you can't scroll bellow the fold, although maybe just in foundation??

Comment: Then you need to find another solution to make your footer sticky. My answer your fix your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdLyGQ But I can't know what's your code. Maybe some of these tricks may help you: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting this.

Comment: Personally I do hate to use display: table and display:table row on block elements. Well, I do hate any type of table behaviour since ie7. But not everybody agrees... yet. gl (btw I sugeest you add foundation tag to your question. It may help to get a better answer)

Comment: Yeah I hate display: table too.